# How to not use sudo in XAMPP?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, xampp

I am using XAMPP on Ubuntu 20.04. It has been installed at the location opt/lampp/ location.

As usual before writing any code I am saving my php file within opt/lampp/htdocs location.

Now, every time I make changes to any file or want to save it I have to use the command line with sudo and obviously type my password again and again and again.

Could there be a way around this?

And not install xampp in root directory or but some other directory which is not within root directory?

Thank you.

Comment: You can make aliases or virtual hosts in Apache to point to anywhere on your filesystem (or just use symlinks via the filesystem itself). You're not restricted to the folder where XAMPP is installed, that's just the basic default. You don't need to re-install anything, just do some configuration in Apache. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/index.html

Comment: Just log in as root if you are sitting in there for that long. sudo is for one off additions, not continuous work.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to the problem. Now I can create files with in the specific folder of htdocs.

My location of installation of xampp was default one `opt/lampp`

Go the parent folder of htdocs that is /lampp and type

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ./htdocs
```

Now go to the parent folder of ./lampp and type

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ./lampp/
```

Here what we basically did was change the permission to create folder and make changes to the file to the location where we have installed xampp.